# why does this code triggers a breakpoint for certain number of digit?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, runtime-error

I want to separate digits of a given number 3-by-3.

> Input: 1234567
>   Output: 1,234,567

And I've written the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string StringIn;
    string::iterator it1, it2;
    cout << "Enter a number with any number of digits: ";
    cin >> StringIn;
    unsigned int len = StringIn.length();
    it1 = StringIn.end();
    if (len % 3 == 0)
        for (int i = 1; i < len / 3; i++)
        {
            it2 = it1 - 3 * i;
            StringIn.insert(it2, ',');
        }
    else
        for (int i = 1; i <= len / 3; i++)
        {
            it2 = it1 - 3 * i;
            StringIn.insert(it2, ',');
        }
    cout << StringIn << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

As you see in the following photos, the code works just fine for a number with

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 number of digits
[image]

16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 number of digits

[image]

32, 33, 34, 35, 36 number of digits

[image]

But it triggers a breakpoint for certain number of digits. Those certain number of digits are 13, 14, 15, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31

Here I've tracked the code for 13 digits.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: `StringIn` is updated but not the iterator `it1`, which could result in undefined behavior.

Comment: It does result in UB. Usually string implements `end` as pointer past the end of allocated array. On reallocation which can happen in insertion the old array is deallocated. So `it2 = it1 - 3 * i;` also points to deallocated array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string StringIn;
    cout << "Enter a number with any number of digits: ";
    cin >> StringIn;
    unsigned int len = StringIn.length();
    if (len % 3 == 0)
        for (int i = 1; i < len / 3; i++)
            StringIn.insert(StringIn.end() - (4 * i - 1), ',');
    else
        for (int i = 1; i <= len / 3; i++)
            StringIn.insert(StringIn.end() - (4 * i - 1), ',');
    cout << StringIn << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

In the [previous version of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56518388/1245120), `it1` which pointed to the end of the string was not updated while `StringIn` and `it2` were updated. So I wrote the line

```
it1 = StringIn.end();
```

inside the loop by

```
StringIn.insert(StringIn.end() - (4 * i - 1), ',');
```

but since the string is modified, there should be a minor change in the expression for each iteration.
Consider:

```
1234567890123456789012
```

when `i=1`, the `','` character should be inserted in `end-3`

```
1234567890123456789,012
```

when `i=2`, the `','` character should be inserted in `end-7` not in `end-6` because a `','` was inserted in the previous iteration

```
1234567890123456,789,012
```

when `i=3`, the `','` character should be inserted in `end-11` not in `end-9` because two `','` were inserted in the previous iteration.

So in the `i`th iteration, `(i-1)` numbers of `','` was inserted from the previous iterations. In order to insert `','` in the right place, we should go back `3 * i + (i - 1)` steps from the end.

That's why I've written the lines 19 and 22 as this form

[image]

Comment: @user4581301 I did

Answer (score 2):

The reasons why it doesn't work for you is in the comments to your post. For the answer, the following code should do the job for you:

```
string str;
string::iterator it;
cout << "Enter a number with any number of digits: ";
cin >> str;
if (str.size() > 3) {
    it = str.end() - 3; // Take the first place where there should be a comma
    while (it > StringIn.begin()) { // Make sure that you are still in a string's place
        if (it - str.begin() > 3)
            it = str.insert(it, ',') - 3; // Insert a comma in the right place, and move to the next comma place
        else it = str.begin();
    }
}
cout << str << endl;
```

Comment: but the cod you've written will trigger a breakpoint at line 5 `it = str.end() - 3; ` if the length of the `str` is less than 3

Comment: @SepidehAbadppour I am not sure if it UB, but wen I tested this program it didn't. I don't change or read the value there if the str have no char there, i just save the address in the iterator. Did you try that code and it crashed?

Comment: Yes, I did. Here are two photos which show where the breakpoints are triggered [photo1](http://s4.picofile.com/file/8363123868/Capture1.JPG) and [photo2](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8363123676/Capture.JPG)

Comment: @SepidehAbadppour I ran it on ubuntu.. Pure c++ won't trigger it. Anyway, I'll add check :)